# Tagging news and filter them afterwards

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, newsfeed

Currently I´m trying to figure out whether is it possible to tag my news with a # or something else and then to create a news feed where every user can filter individualy by them self the news regarding the #.

So for example I have news with the titel "Information for all" and there at the bottom of the text I place tags like e.g. #forall.
Then the user can go on the site "my news feed" and filter there the news web part. When he enteres the tag #forall the news "Information for all" should show up.

Can somebody help me with this request? Is this possible? And if so, how?

Thansk in advance!
Best regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

What did you mean tag news?

We could tag news page as mentioned in this article:

https://joannecklein.com/2018/07/11/tagging-modern-pages-in-sharepoint-online/

Also an article about News web part in SharePoint online for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165